# When using JWT with Laravel and Axios, JWT works but other routes always returns 401 Unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, axios, jwt

I have successfully implemented JWT in Laravel and everything is working fine. Login, Logout.

But every time I want to add a new route in my `routes/api.php` and try to use it with an controller, I get a `401 Unauthenticated`. *It seems as if the controller is not addressed because no `var_dump` comes back.*

My `config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
   'web' => [
       'driver' => 'session',
       'provider' => 'users',
   ],

   'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

My Request:

```
let myConfig = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + 'JWT_SECRET'
    }
}

axios.get('http://localhost/api/getcashboxes', myConfig)
.then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

My `routes/api.php`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('getcashboxes', 'CashboxController@getcashboxes')->name('getcashboxes');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function ($router) {

    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

});
```

My `CashboxController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CashboxController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
        //$this->middleware('auth:api'); //Does not work too
    }

    public function getcashboxes()
    {
        var_dump("Hello World :)");
    }
}
```

Request-Header:

```
Accept
    application/json, text/plain, 
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate
Accept-Language
    de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Authorization
    Bearer 5zqyH1BrQUbiDRefurc5XaduzaTyCXPlcPXbodDHhsgdjJHU1dDHhsgdjefur
Cache-Control
    max-age=0
Connection
    keep-alive
Cookie
    XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlVjRFwvYkRvaSs3cDBCVFkxMFZtZkhRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Imw4WlZ3RlwvVjNQemZOaTRQXC84MDlrd01uc0dFeUZ4eCtuR29jcWFqTGZBY3RkdzdFdFpzWjB4UDZOQzhQYXRTUCIsIm1hYyI6ImE5ODFkODM1ODU3M2Q3ZDEyZDY1NjdiYTY3ZGJkN2FlNGIzYWRiZTcxNjI4ODc3MmZkYzg3MGZjMzhmODlhODkifQ%3D%3D; buywatchvue_session=eyJpdiI6IjFSb25ZdmthalF2Tm1TWjM4cnUzRkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQms0SDNGNlFPcXM1YVR2MTZzeEJpRkc1MnlPeFlGOW5IRlRVR0pTZWI3MUk2XC9RMUdsYVp5SWQyTnJRcitoazIiLCJtYWMiOiI0ZmYyNjQxOWY0NjAxNzM4NzY2YzBmYjY2Mjc2OTcyNTE0ZjVkYzdlMDU2YzE0MWE4Y2U2MzZmNTFkNzU2MWY4In0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ik4wNGRJM3Q5QU5KRUlIbWZoaUE4VkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNmNLb09JeU5DRksxM1VNMElPNDNQb1NseVNJYWdTdXpZdnZyS1RuMlVRY043OUJcLzREMXhkaWR3TmR6ZklWaWIiLCJtYWMiOiJmYWViNzIxMmZjYTU1N2UwYmI2OTU3YzAyNmFmNzM3NjAyMzY5N2Q2MTAyMzEwNzc1MDZlZWQzMjE4YWZiN2UyIn0%3D
Host
    localhost
Referer
    http://localhost
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
X-CSRF-TOKEN
    DClSR93LzbeM4SZQ9OzZJ89s5jtiNFOfkWabYMSJ
X-Requested-With
    XMLHttpRequest
X-XSRF-TOKEN
    eyJpdiI6IlVjRFwvYkRvaSs3cDBCVFkxMFZtZkhRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Imw4WlZ3RlwvVjNQemZOaTRQXC84MDlrd01uc0dFeUZ4eCtuR29jcWFqTGZBY3RkdzdFdFpzWjB4UDZOQzhQYXRTUCIsIm1hYyI6ImE5ODFkODM1ODU3M2Q3ZDEyZDY1NjdiYTY3ZGJkN2FlNGIzYWRiZTcxNjI4ODc3MmZkYzg3MGZjMzhmODlhODkifQ==
```

Answer-Header:

```
Cache-Control
    no-cache, private
Connection
    Keep-Alive
Content-Length
    30
Content-Type
    application/json
Date
    Sat, 22 Aug 2020 14:12:25 GMT
Keep-Alive
    timeout=5, max=99
Server
    Apache/2.4.37 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1a PHP/7.3.0
Vary
    Authorization
X-Powered-By
    PHP/7.3.0
```

---

Anyone an idea?

Comment: if you check your headers do you see the token being sent?

Comment: I added the headers to my post

Comment: I had a similar issue with this issue. What I think is happening is that the token does not get to the backend hence the 401. I resolved it by creating default headers with axios.

Comment: hm, can you show what you mean?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was a lack of **knowledge** about how JSON Web Tokens (JWT) works.

**The principle explained simply:**
If the user is logged in from the server, he gets a JWT back. This JWT must now be saved on the client side either as a cookie or in local storage. This is needed for later server inquiries.

If a request, that requires authorization, is sent to the server, the JWT must be sent in the header.

So it has to be read from the cookie or the local storage. With `Laravel`, `Vue`, `Vuex`, `Axios` and the `local storage` it can look like this:

Get token from server (`AuthController.php`):

```
public function login()
{
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (! $token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

Login mutation in vuex (`store.js`):

```
mutations: {
    loginSuccess(state, payload) {
        state.auth_error = null;
        state.isLoggedIn = true;
        state.loading = false;
        state.currentUser = Object.assign({}, payload.user, {token: payload.access_token});
    
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.currentUser));
    },
},
```

Get the local user, included the JWT token:

```
function getLocalUser() {
    const userStr = localStorage.getItem("user");

    if(!userStr) {
        return null;
    }

    return JSON.parse(userStr);
}
```

**Create an axios-request using the JWT-Token from the local store:**

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost/api'
});

instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${getLocalUser().token}`;

instance.get('/test')
.then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

---

I hope I can help someone with this. Otherwise there is more information about JWT [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token). Thanks to **Jonathan Akwetey Okine** for the inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an instance of axios and use it like I did.

```
const instance = axios.create({
baseURL: 'http://localhost/api'
});

instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;

instance.get('/getcashboxes')
.then(res => {
console.log(res.data)
}).catch(err => {
console.log(err)
 })
```

Please let me know if it helps you fix the issue.

Comment: Hm, it wont work, but... can you tell me where you get `${JWT_SECRET}` from and what it looks like? For me JWT_SECRET is in the `.env` and I simply copied it out for testing.

Comment: Sorry, why are you saying it won't work? the variable there is supposed to be the token. Sorry.  where do you store the token after you get it?

Comment: I thought that was what you were passing as your token.

Comment: Uh Sorry, not "it wont" i meant "didn't". I am now wondering if I am simply using the wrong token. Shouldn't it look aaaa.bbbb.cccc? How do you get the token from .env-File?

Comment: Can you tell me where you store your token after you get it?  It could be that you are using the wrong token, it could be that the token has expired. Yes, jwt tokens looks like aaaa.bbb.cccc. But where do you store it?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help and your time. I think this could be the fault. Can you show me what you mean with "where do you store the token?". I only generate a token with `php artisan jwt:secret` and copy paste it at the `${token}` you wrote in your example above. `instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer le8rZEBoSF9zcnLxc5LhD1Cedu3pjdNkZ8pAFRX9M2fdj8PeNeTecM4HcTsf17IL";`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220280/discussion-between-tenarius-and-jonathan-akwetey-okine).